# why react post to localhost not working? (mock API)

Tags: reactjs, http, post

I'm going to use the fetch function to send a "post" using MOCK API. However, the post is not sent and 404 errors continue to appear.

Is it not possible to post on the localhost?

```
<WriteSubmitButton onClick={onDiaryPost}> Make ! </WriteSubmitButton>
```

```
const onDiaryPost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data/diaryList.json', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        date: write.date,
        title: write.title,
        text: write.text,
      }),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if (res.success) {
          alert('add new something');
        }
      });
  };
```

why 404 not found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `POST` on local `json` file. Instead of you can create a basic `json-server` on your local machine. It is very simple and usable. You only need to install it

```bash
npm install -g json-server
```

then start it

```bash
json-server --watch diaryList.json
```

For further information please check their documentation:
https://github.com/typicode/json-server